# Windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

Windows phone 8 emulator: doesn't connect VPN.
I'm trying to connect internet via Windows Phone 8 Emulator using VPN connection.  It doesn't connect VPN, it uses only local watchguard.

Please advice.

Comment: A little more information about what you have done so far would be a must to help you.

Comment: I develop a windows phone 8 app using VS2013 and consuming web service  .  But web service are allowed to connected only via VPN.  We have local watch guard login to connect internet and VPN.  VPN will be enable via watch guard and able to access internet using VPN.  When run app it is asking as to login watch guard again, not a able to connect web service directly via VPN.

Answer (score 1):

First connect to your VPN and add a bridge using Hyper-V Switch Manager and set it to your primary connection. Try start your emulator again.

Answer (score 0):

Start internet explorer in the Emulator ,try to open any website ,it must ask for the login again,provide your credentials there and log in .Once logged in successfully try to call webservice again ,it should be successfull.

Answer (score 0):

VPN functionality wasn't there in WP8 emulator. It came in WP 8.1. So, you might want to upgrade your project and try.